# How to place a layout below toolbar in collapsing toolbar layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want a collapsing toolbar layout in my app. For this I have added the collapsing toolbar inside the app bar. I have added the relative layout with some text views under the layout. This relative layout I want to show below the toolbar and it should get collapsed till the toolbar.

For now as I have added this, Its getting merged with the toolbar. Looks like below:

[image]

EDIT : Edited with nested scroll view. Scrolls till the status bar, Should scroll till the toolbar.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Event Name"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/eventName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.siddhi.meavita.Activities.PlanDetailsActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_plan_details">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PLAN"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:text="Schedule"
                android:id="@+id/schedule"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/list_background" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:text="Check List"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_background" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Vendors"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_background" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Invitee"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_background" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

How can I place this below toolbar and scroll upto the toolbar? Thank you..

Answer (score 12):

Add this line into your RelativeLayout.

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: i added this to my relative layout with the answer of Alexander. Now it get's collapsed completely till the status bar i want it to be collapsed till the toolbar. @Chandrakant Dvivedi

Comment: add app:layout_collapseMode="pin"  to Toolbar

Answer (score 5):

Put a margin to the RelativeLayout android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/eventName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Event Name"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/eventName"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Date"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/time"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Time"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="adlfjsd adsf adsf dsafasd fsda f af dsaf afl djsaflk sjdafl jsalf jsdalf jsdal fjasdl fjalsd jflas jflsa djfdl"
            android:textSize="100sp"/>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you mean I should use linear layout to wrap text views instead of relative layout? I tried doing this but still it gave same result. @Alexander

Comment: I have updated my answer. It should be something like this. Also in this case I advise you using **LinearLayout** instead of **RelativeLayout**

Comment: Ok  tried this. It comes below the toolbar, but when i scroll it everything gets scrolled up till the status bar. I only want it to be scrolled till the toolbar. @Alexander

Comment: Please check my edited question, added updated layout. @ Alexander

Comment: I have tested it. An it scrolled until toolbar @user6265109

Comment: you mean I should add the relative layout with buttons in nested scrollview? check the edited question tried it still works same. @Alexander

Comment: Did you post your layout which you are using now?

Comment: yes, please see the edited question. It has latest updated code. @Alexander

Comment: I don't see using **CoordinatorLayout**. It should be the root layout.

Comment: by mistake it's not posted but it has in the code.@Alexander

Comment: I also tested ur code as it is, it dose not scroll till the toolbar srolls up to the status bar. @Alexander

Comment: it's very strange... Could you pls test my code in a new project. Because I've tested it and it works...

Comment: i too tested your code but it gets scrolled upto the status bar. toolbar gets disappear. @Alexander

Comment: what is android version? Do you test on emulator or real device?

Comment: android 6.0 on real device. @ Alexander

Comment: I achieved this by putting a topMargin equal to the height of the toolbar.  android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

Answer (score 0):

Always Put your AppBarLayout above your Layout, this solution is tested.. U can try..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customfontdemo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3">
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#428BCA"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay" >
        <lloyd.sp.com.studentportal.utils.MyTextview
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Latest Attendance"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            customfontdemo:fontName="OpenSans-Semibold.ttf"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_gravity = "right"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/signout"
            android:onClick="dosignout"
            android:src="@drawable/logout_icon"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <Button

        android:text="Status"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView10" />

    <Button
        android:text="Date"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="Subject"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"

        />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewLatestAttendance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is NOT recommended as per the material design reference here: https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/