# How to use collapsing toolbar for vertical views

Tags: android, android-layout

In my activity,I have a toolbar and the view should be displayed below toolbar (Like Linearlayout) and listview as follows,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.xyz.abc.MainPage">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/view">

     <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <RelativeLayout
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <FrameLayout
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:id="@+id/header_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@+id/header_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
   </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<FrameLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/body_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> I want to use hide the view below toolbar (Relative layout) when the listview is scrolled [like this](http://codebzrk.com/2017/08/13/collapsing-toolbar-recycler-view-android/). But It is not working for my case . I tried every solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386184/how-to-place-a-layout-below-toolbar-in-collapsing-toolbar-layout) . Even changing CoordinatorLayout to RelativeLayout doesn't work.

In my xml, the framelayouts will be replaced at runtime.

Guide me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use scrollview or nested scrollview with collapsing toolbar.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:id="@+id/appbar_"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="192dp"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
   android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
   app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
   app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
   app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/header"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="192dp"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:src="@drawable/bg2"
       app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

  </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Use Scrollview here
     
Now you can continue with your framelayout or watevr you want to use

Comment: I need the view below toolbar title .

Comment: after this </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout> you can use nestedview or scrollview and under that you can code. And this code will work after the toolbar. Listen whatevr ui you want in toolbar just code above toolbar ,beacuse Toolbar is the last child of the CollapsingToolbarLayout. This ensures that the views are drawn in the correct order.after closing of appbarlayout you rest of ui will work.

Comment: As you said, I have changed my code, But the title of the activity is enlarged to the height of actionbar . The whole view in actionbar is collapsed not linear.